# Cybersource Integration with ASP.NET

Tags: asp.net, sharepoint, cybersource

Dears,

I am following the below link to integrate the cybersource payment gateway into one of our ASP.NET site.

https://searchcode.com/codesearch/view/10126551/

on line 192 as depicted below:

```
        ReplyMessage reply = CyberSource.Clients.SoapClient.RunTransaction(config, request);

        if ("ACCEPT".Equals(reply.decision.ToUpper()))
        {
            trans.GatewayResponse = reply.decision;
            trans.TransactionNotes = ProcessReply(reply);
            trans.AuthorizationCode = reply.ccAuthReply.authorizationCode;
        }

        if ("REJECT".Equals(reply.decision.ToUpper()))
        {
            throw new Exception("Declined:  " + ProcessReply(reply));
        }
```

it should hit the cybersource gateway in order to fill the credit card information as below.

[screen shot cybersource](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IgnNd.png)

but its not happening.

any idea why its not happening?

thanks in advance,

Ammar

Comment: Usually an ssl issue, try adding `System.Net.ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = System.Net.SecurityProtocolType.Tls12` before your request. You may need to adjust the TLS version

Comment: thanks @aterry. i already added that line but it didn't work. :(

Comment: is an exception thrown by the proxy or is the reply just empty?

Comment: thanks a lot @aterry. I was getting the reply as ACCEPTED. before getting accepted the request should go to the cybersource page for me to enter credit card details. That is not happening. please kindly advise.

Answer (score 0):

The issue is that you're trying to integrate with Secure Acceptance using the SOAPI SDK. SA is a totally different product with its own API and integration method. You can find the documentation including examples for ASP.NET here: http://apps.cybersource.com/library/documentation/dev_guides/Secure_Acceptance_WM/Secure_Acceptance_WM.pdf